# How can I print a 1D array to be 3 x 3 and how can I have an RNG computer check values and to keep searching for an empty space?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

I have been working on a 1D Tic Tac Toe project for a while now, and I am still fairly new to coding, so I have a couple questions/issues.

- To start off, I am having issues with printing the board as a 1D String array. Primarily setting it up in the three x three fashion with the 'blanks' represented as '-'.

  ```
  //global variables

  static int ArrayLength = 9;

  static String[] board = new String[ArrayLength];

  static int maxVal = ArrayLength;


  static void PrntBoard() 

  {
      for (int cntr = '-'; cntr < maxVal; cntr++) 
  {

   System.out.println(board[cntr]);


         }
  }
  ```
- I am also experiencing issues with my Computer Moves, as I keep getting errors with the computer unable to wrap around the array to eventually find an empty space and checking if a space is available in the first place.

  static void CompMove() {

  ```
  int space = 0;

  //keep asking till they get an empty one

      //have the comp random pick a spot
      space = RNG.nextInt(9);
      //check
      while (board[space].equals('X') || board[space].equals('O'));
      {
          space = RNG.nextInt(9)-1;

      }



  //fill in the game board with the valid position
  if (board[space].equals('-')) {
      board[space].equals('O');
      PrntBoard();
  }
  int lastspace = space;

  }
  ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am still, quite frankly, a novice and do not possess much knowledge in coding. Thank you.

Comment: [xkcd: 832](https://xkcd.com/832/) should do better than random picks.

Comment: Of course, but at this time I am attempting to create a ‘dumb computer’ to serve the role as the other player.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, please take a look on [Java Language Basic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) to learn some basic concept.
2. For the `printBoard` method, the for condition should start from 0 to `maxVal`, instead of using `char` `'-'`, which is converted to `int` **45**, check out [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for details.
3. For the `CompMove` method, the `equals` comparison fails as you are comparing `String(board[space])` with `Character('X')`, which is of different types. Please note that **'X'** is different to **"X"** in Java.
4. To fill in the game board with the valid position, `board[space].equals('O');` is not what you need, `equals` only do the comparison and not setting value. Use `board[space] = "O");` instead.

Please try the following code to verify the above points.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("'-' converted to int is " + (int) '-');
    System.out.println("\"X\".equals('X')? " + "X".equals('X'));
    String[] board = new String[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      board[i] = "-";
    }
    System.out.println("Before change\t" + Arrays.toString(board));
    board[0] = "O";
    System.out.println("After change\t" + Arrays.toString(board));
  }
```

Finally, please try to follow the [Java Naming Convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), method and variable name should start with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

In First example you have error in for loop. Should be:

```
for(int cntr=0; cntr<board.length; cntr++) {
        System.out.println(board[cntr]);
    }
```

In your case `int cntr='-'` is this same as 'int cntr=92`(because you cast char '-' to int and char '-' is number 92) but you have initialized array with 9 positions length.

In second example you have to remove semicolon next to while loop. Should be:

```
while (board[space].equals('X') || board[space].equals('O')){
        space = RNG.nextInt(9)-1;
    }
```

in your case `while (board[space].equals('X') || board[space].equals('O'));` you will never get into brakets